# ResponseValidationFailed: reason unacceptableStatusCode (code: 404)

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I am creating a Sign in page using **POST Method** of **Alamofire**. I am struggling with the error appearing when I enabled the breakpoint of my codes. I am using Alamofire. Why do I encounter this kind of error. Please see [image: this]

**Alamofire request **

```
 `class APIService
  {
   let eventAPIKey: String
   let eventBaseURL: URL?

   static let kEventID = "id"
   init(APIKey: String)
   {
    self.eventAPIKey = APIKey
    eventBaseURL = URL(string: BASE_URL)
   }

   func validatePasscode(eventCode: String, completion: @escaping (Event?) -> Void)
   {
   if let passcodeURL = URL (string: PASSCODE_CHECKER_URL) {


    Alamofire.request(passcodeURL, method: .post).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            if let eventJSON = response.result.value{
                let eventObject:Dictionary = eventJSON as! Dictionary<String, Any>

                let eventidObject: Dictionary = eventObject[APIService.kEventID] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                let event:String = eventidObject[APIService.kEventID] as! String
                print(event)

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(error)")
          }
        }

       }
    }
```

`

Comment: 404 is not found http status code. Please check your url

Comment: Your server sent reponse code 404 (not found)  see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404. Maybe you should check the URL or your server.

Comment: It is the correct URL but code404 is still showing. thanks